# передача позиции putExtra

Tags: android

Суть вопроса такова, нужно передать позицию с данного активити,в активити стоящую под номером 3,при этом перети в активити под номер 2

```
 intent = new Intent(f1.this, f2.class);
                          intent.putExtra("positionB",position);
                        startActivity(intent);
```

помогите решить данную проблему ,думаю я делаю что то не так ,так как передаю позицию и перехожу во вторую активити

Comment: `Отправить экстру на третью но перейти на вторую` - это как? Экстру можно положить в интент, тоесть перейти на третью нужно будет 100%. Вы либо структуру приложения плохо продумали, либо обьясняете не так

Comment: суть приложения такова ,в каждом активити имеется меню с выбором кое чего -это не так важно,например в 1-активити марка телефона ,во втором 2-активити его память,и в 3 активити я должен получить все выбранные позиции для ввывода результата

Comment: Как то глупо для этого каждую активность создавать.. На одной нельзя сделать?

Comment: таковы требования заказчика

Comment: Можно было сделать имитацию перехода, куда проще...

Comment: возможно можно было буду знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передайте данные из Первой Активити во второй, там соберите все вместе, вы ведь все равно еще не в третьем и передайте со Второго Активити в Третий все, что необходимо.

Если данных ну очень много, тогда советую создать вам базу данных sqlite. Сохраняйте туда каждый раз при изменении данных или при выходе из какого-либо Активити. При входе в другое Активити извлекайте данные из БД.

Активити 1 - отправляем

```
Intent intent_1 = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent_1.putExtra("MY_KEY_1", "samsung");
intent_1.putExtra("MY_KEY_2", "google");
intent_1.putExtra("MY_KEY_3", "alcatel");
intent_1.putExtra("MY_KEY_4", "meizu");

startActivity(intent_1);
```

Активити 2 - получаем

```
String MY_KEY_1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_1");
String MY_KEY_2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_2");
String MY_KEY_3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_3");
String MY_KEY_4 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_4");
```

Активити 2 - отправляем

```
Intent intent_2 = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_1", MY_KEY_1);
intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_2", MY_KEY_2);
intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_3", MY_KEY_3);
intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_4", MY_KEY_4);

intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_5", 1);
intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_6", 2);
intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_7", 3);
intent_2.putExtra("MY_KEY_8", 4);

startActivity(intent_2);
```

Активити 3 - получаем

```
String MY_KEY_1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_1");
String MY_KEY_2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_2");
String MY_KEY_3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_3");
String MY_KEY_4 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_KEY_4");

int MY_KEY_5 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_KEY_5");
int MY_KEY_6 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_KEY_6");
int MY_KEY_7 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_KEY_7");
int MY_KEY_8 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("MY_KEY_8");
```

По моему как-то так (:

Comment: я понял идею но как реализовать?   positionB = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("positionB"); вот я принимаю позицию во втором как потом эту позицию передать в 3 активити

Comment: @fcbarcafc: лично я выбрал для себя в свое время базу данных.